# Parsing JsonObjectRequest

Tags: java, android, json

I am new to Android and JAVA and I am trying to parse a json response. I know how to parse jsonarray but no Idea how to parse jsonobject. Can someone tell me how? Below is my Response.

```
{"118":{"garment_color":"Blue","garment_name":"skjhkds","garment_price":"232"},"119":{"garment_color":"hjsadjjs","garment_name":"sdasd","garment_price":"23478"}}
```

And this is how parsed jsonarray.

```
public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){

    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

        GetDataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new GetDataAdapter();

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {

            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            GetDataAdapter2.setImageTitleNamee(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_TITLE_NAME));
            //GetDataAdapter2.setImageServerLarger(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_LARGER));

            GetDataAdapter2.setImageServerUrl(json.getString(JSON_IMAGE_URL));
            GetDataAdapter2.setMrp_price(json.getString(JSON_MRP_PRICE));
            GetDataAdapter2.setDisc_price(json.getString(JSON_DISC_PRICE));

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GetDataAdapter1.add(GetDataAdapter2);
    }

    recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(GetDataAdapter1, this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
}
```

Please Someone help. Thanks.

Comment: you need to make JSONObject request instead of JSONArray request

Comment: Your response was JSONObject not JSONArray. use JSONObject for proper result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library, where you give it the json object/array/string and it automatically parses it into a java object. Note that you have to define the java class with the appropriate fields.

EDIT: So here's an answer that goes with the suggested guidelines:

First create your model classes just like you will receive them from the server:

```
public class MyServerObject {
    MyGarment jsonKeyName;
}

public class MyGarment {
    String garment_color;
    String garment_name;
    String garment_price;
}
```

Next, after receiving your json string, parse it using Gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json= "{"jsonKeyName":{"garment_color":"Blue","garment_name":"skjhkds","garment_price":"232"};

MyServerObject serverObject = gson.fromJson(json, MyServerObject.class);
```

Now, you can access your Garment object from your server object with all the values parsed correctly. Also note that if you're receiving a json array you could add the object as a list in your `MyServerObject.class`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mate...Got it

Answer (score 0):

**[as per my above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664493/parsing-jsonobjectrequest/46664802#comment80277184_46664493)**

you need to make JSONObject request instead of JSONArray request

try this to parse your JSON Response

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject("Response");

            JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonObject.getJSONObject("118");
            String garment_color=jsonObject1.getString("garment_color");
            String garment_name=jsonObject1.getString("garment_name");
            String garment_price=jsonObject1.getString("garment_price");

            JSONObject jsonObject2=jsonObject.getJSONObject("119");
            String garment_color2=jsonObject1.getString("garment_color");
            String garment_name2=jsonObject1.getString("garment_name");
            String garment_price2=jsonObject1.getString("garment_price");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This isn't using a JSONObjectRequest. You don't parse need to any strings using it

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringRequest` instead of `JSONObject/JSONArray` request and finally fetch value like this:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(YOUR JSON RESPONSE);
String s1 = object.getJSONObject("118").getString("garment_color");
```

Comment: If the response is always JSON, this isn't necessary